# virtualenv can't find python2

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm on a mac, which comes with python 2.7 installed, so I should have the required version.

At least, I believe that's the problem. I'm getting an error when trying to run `make install` for a project, and getting the following error:

```
The executable python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist
make: *** [bin/python] Error 3
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
virtualenv --python=python3 fibonacci_env
```

Point out which python

Answer (score 6):

Specify the full path to the Python interpreter (not sure if this is the right path - haven't used MacOs):

```
mkvirtualenv myenv --python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

or smth like:

```
--python=$(which python)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 is part of system framework and is located here:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`

If you want to create a virtualenv with python2.7 on macOS Sierra do this:

`virtualenv -p /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python my_venv`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the python version you want to use

> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv